# Apply diff() and replace elements in original data.frame with NA

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, apply

I have a little problem I'd need your help with. I have the following data frame:

```
set.seed(1000)
test = data.frame(a = sample(10, replace=T), b = sample(10, replace=T), c=rep(NA, 10))

> test
   a  b  c
1  1  6 NA
2  2  4 NA
3  6  3 NA
4  6  9 NA
5  1  5 NA
6  4  3 NA
7  5  1 NA
8  3  7 NA
9  5 10 NA
10 4  2 NA
```

and perform the diff() function to compute difference between consecutive rows within each column

```
test2 = abs(apply(test, 2, diff))

> test2
     a b  c
[1,] 1 2 NA
[2,] 4 1 NA
[3,] 0 6 NA
[4,] 5 4 NA
[5,] 3 2 NA
[6,] 1 2 NA
[7,] 2 6 NA
[8,] 2 3 NA
[9,] 1 8 NA
```

I would like to replace those elements in 'test' where the difference in test2 is, say, greater than/equal to 4, with NA values. I would expect, for example, test[3,1] to become NA, since its diff in test2[2,1] is >= 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 test2 <- abs(apply(test,2,function(x) c(NA, diff(x))))
```

#### Update

Based on the new information:

```
test[!is.na(test2) & test2 >4] <- NA
test
#   a  b  c
# 1   4  4 NA
# 2   8  8 NA
# 3  NA  4 NA
# 4  NA NA NA
# 5   6  8 NA
# 6  NA NA NA
# 7  NA  5 NA
# 8   6  7 NA
# 9   3 NA NA
# 10  3 NA NA
```

Comment: Let me be more precise on what you asked. I would need to replace the original value inside 'test' with NA in case that condition is verified. You solution seems to work in identifying the subset of 'test' where that happens. However, I automatically need to replace those original values with NA (not the entire row, rather only the single elements)

Comment: @user20038.  I updated the code.  Hopefully, it helps.  Your input dataset as shown in the question seems to be not based on the `set.seed(1000)`.

Comment: hey akrun, what was that solution you posted prior to this, where you would get the indexes (row-column) out of the function?

Comment: @user20038, which(!is.na(test2) & test2 <=4,arr.ind=T)